# usage of ng-if and ng-switch inside ng-repeat fails

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to compare `userId` with `currentuserId` and when the condition of action is `approve` i am trying to populate checkboxes. But my `ng-if` seems to be failing always. How can i do this better . ng-switch works fine . Should i follow some other way ? When the user and currentuser id's match i dont want to enable checkboxes to them

```
<tr ng-repeat="details in searchresponse">
  <td class=list align=center ng-switch="details.action">
    <span ng-switch-when="View">
            <input type="checkbox" name="ent" id="ent" ng-model="details.selected">
        </span>
    <span ng-switch-when="Approve">
        <ng-if='details.UserId' != 'details.currentUserId'><input type="checkbox" name="ent" id="ent" ng-model="details.selected">
     </span>
```

Answer (score 3):

### HTML Attributes

As already stated in the other answers you need to correctly embrace your HTML attributes in quotes to make any angularJS magic work. For this purpose, you should accustom yourself to use always the same type of quotes (typically double quotes `"statement"` for any HTML attributes, while using the other type (respectively single quotes `'string'`) to embrace Strings within AngularJS statements.

In your example, there is no need to put variable names into additional quotes, as you wouldn't want them to be evaluated as there literal strings.

Changing

`ng-if='details.UserId' != 'details.currentUserId'`

to

`ng-if="details.UserId != details.currentUserId"`

### Use `ng-if` only as attribute

Further, it is not allowed to use the [`ng-if` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) in any other ways as in an HTML attribute of an arbitrary HTML Node. (This is indicated in its directive definition with a [`restrict: 'A'`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) which explicitly limits the use to attributes. Which would further change your code from

`<ng-if="details.UserId != details.currentUserId">`

to

`<div ng-if="details.UserId != details.currentUserId">`

### Embracing HTML Tags

The `<ng-if>` tag of your example does additionally not surround any other elements, nor does it resemble a self-closing HTML node such as `<input />`. There are only a handful of tags which support such an exceptional use.

### Isolated `ng-if`scope

If you still get problems, resolving your AngularJS template, or scope variables you should consider that `ng-if` does create an isolated scope, as the concerning container object is actually removed from the DOM, or respectively inserted into the DOM depending on its conditional statement. (This might either be especially useful if you want to prevent the background rendering of massive junks of code. Or you might also generate a huge amount of unnecessary high workload for elements which are typically displayed and hidden again multiple times on a single page visit)

The `ng-show` and `ng-hide` offer a slightly different approach by simply hiding the respective elements (applying a standard CSS `display:none` attribute/class)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<ng-if='details.UserId' != 'details.currentUserId'><input type="checkbox" name="ent" id="ent" ng-model="details.selected">
```

do

```
<span ng-if="details.UserId != details.currentUserId"><input type="checkbox" name="ent" id="ent" ng-model="details.selected" /></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the hyphens '

```
 <ng-if='details.UserId!=details.currentUserId'>...
```

Comment: it didnt work !! I tried this before posting here .Now also i tried it

Comment: removing those wrong hyphens is a valid remark. But `<ng-if>` is still not a valid HTML node or AngularJS directive use. Use of `ng-if` is only allowed as an attribute.